# Titianium Error: Could not find module localeStrings for architecture i386

Tags: ios, appcelerator-mobile

This is my first Titianium project and I just run through the error when using iOS simulator:

```
Titianium Error: Could not find module localeStrings for architecture i386
```

What is the problem ? Where can I find and download that module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a LiveView problem we're currently fixing. Turn off LiveView for the moment.